# Converting database query results from strings to tuples efficiently

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, python-2.7

I have an sqlite query which returns the following python list of tuples:

```
[(u'1623,0.0,1651,2.0e-06,1679,5.0e-06,1707,7.0e-06,1735,9.0e-06,1762,1.1e-05,1790,1.4e-05'),
( u'1933,458273.7,1940,460182.6,1947,464019.3,1954,465922.8,1961,467856.0,1968,479385.0')]
```

Each string here contains a tuple of x,y pairs i.e.one item is 1623,0.0
The output which I want is:

```
[(1623,0.0,1651,2.0e-06,1679,5.0e-06,1707,7.0e-06,1735,9.0e-06,1762,1.1e-05,1790,1.4e-05),
(1933,458273.7,1940,460182.6,1947,464019.3,1954,465922.8,1961,467856.0,1968,479385.0)]
```

Is there an efficient way to perform this translation?

Maybe it can be performed at the sql level but I dont think so, my query is as follows:

```
select group_concat( COALESCE(timestamp, "")
                     || COALESCE(",", "")
                     || COALESCE(value, "") )
              from table where type='VALUE' group by eventid;
```

I cant find a way to concatenate more than one column without converting it to a string

Comment: Why are you concatenating columns in the first place? Why not just query for `timestamp, value`?

Comment: And `COALESCE(",", "")` is always going to be `","`, so why are you using `COALESCE` there at all?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I cant do a simple query of timestamp, value since they are grouped by a field called eventID. If I did "select eventID group_concat( COALESCE(timestamp, "") ...." 
I would get: 
[(1 | "data1, data2, data3"), (2|"data1, data2, data3")]

so the tuples in the final result are due to the eventIDs depicting a specific group.

Valid comment on COALESCE I can remove that :) Thanks

Comment: p.s that is the reason I am using the "group_concat" and "group by" keywords

Comment: Yes, I see what you are trying to do here, and you are going about it the wrong way. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't group in SQL, group in Python and avoid having to serialize then unserialize your values:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


cursor.execute('''select eventid, timestamp, value from table
                  where type="VALUE" order by eventid''')
for eventid, rows in groupby(cursor, itemgetter(0)):
    print eventid
    for _, timestamp, value in rows:
        print timestamp, value
```

Use grouping in SQL only when you need to aggregate your data (to sum, calculate averages, count, etc.) not when you need individual rows from the groups for further processing.

If you need your output exactly as described (a tuple with timestamp, value pairs repeated) you can produce that with:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

cursor.execute('''select eventid, timestamp, value from table
                  where type="VALUE" order by eventid''')
result = [tuple(chain.from_iterable(r[1:] for r in rows))
          for eventid, rows in groupby(cursor, itemgetter(0))]
```

e.g. for every unique `eventid` produce a tuple consisting of the chained timestamp and value columns.

Comment: Yes, that seems like the way to go. I thought there might have been some sql magic to do this. Since iterating through alot of elements is quiet slow but there doesnt seem to be a way around this.

Comment: @user1932405: the alternative is to interpret your strings as tuples using `ast.literal_eval()` but that's intensive as well. It is also *more* work for both SQLite and Python.